# How write in java regex any string of characters?

Tags: java, regex

I have a text and  I'd like to write a regular expression to extract the string after second `@`. For example:
`@ some text with letter, digit 123 1234 and symbols {[ @text_to_extract`.
How would I write a regular expression to extract only the string after second `@`. This code seems like a step in the right direction:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@@(.+?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("asdasdas@@textToExtract");
```

This works when text between `@` is empty, but how do I specify any text in a regex?

`Pattern.compile("@(*)@(.+?)");` ?

**Edited:**
One more condition, text can be between `@` and `@` but doesn't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't capture the first group
- Change the plain `*` to `.*`.
- Make the second wildcard greedy, since it will otherwise capture only a single character

---

```
Pattern.compile("@.*@(.+)");
```

Comment: that won't work with more then 2 `@`..Also `.` won't match newlines

Comment: @Anirudh you're right on both counts. But the OP did not say that either one was a requirement. Welcome to the wonderful world of vaguely-specified regex questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The "non-greedy" operator should be removed.  `(.*?)` should be `(.*)` ... Otherwise you match just the minimum of the text after the second @.  Definitely need a "." in front of the *.  It means "0 or more of the proceeding character.  Actually, maybe you want `[^@]*` instead... so it matches anything but the at symbol.. so you're guaranteed to get everything, even if . doesn't match newlines.  Anyway, here's working code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@(*)@(.+?)");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@.*@(.+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("asdasdas@@textToExtract");

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Play with the code here:  http://ideone.com/rxB5Zy

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way

```
Matcher m =Pattern.compile("^[^@]*@[^@]*@([^@]*)").matcher(input);
```